# MapStruct backlink mapping possible?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am new to MapStruct and could not find an answer to my question on google.
I am having a ShoppingCart which has got Samples (among other properties) and each Sample needs a reference back to my ShoppingCart. Is it possible to do such mapping with MapStruct?
Without MapStruct I simply pass a reference to the ShoppingCart to the Samples. This was written by hand:

```
protected ShoppingCart map(Cart cart, DataShareOption dataShareOption) {
//(other stuff)
   for (CartSample cartSample : cart.getCartSamples()) {
       ShoppingCartSample sample = mapCartSample(cartSample, shoppingCart,
       dataShareOption);
       shoppingCart.getSamples().add(sample);
   }
}

protected ShoppingCartSample mapCartSample(CartSample cartSample,
    ShoppingCart shoppingCart, DataShareOption dataShareOption) {

     ShoppingCartSample sample = new ShoppingCartSample();
     sample.setShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
     //(other stuff)
     return sample;
}

// the classes declarations:
// business class
public class ShoppingCart extends ShoppingCartHeader
{
    private List<ShoppingCartSample> samples = new   ArrayList<ShoppingCartSample>();
//rest of the class


// data base class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
public class Cart extends BaseEntity
{
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "cart")
private Set<CartSample> cartSamples = new HashSet<CartSample>();
   // more stuff here


// business class:
  public class ShoppingCartSample
  {
   private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
  // rest of the class


// data base class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart_sample")
public class CartSample
{
   @ManyToOne()
   @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
   private Cart cart;
   // more stuff here
```

Comment: Is the method in the question created by you or MapStruct?

Comment: Does the `ShoppingCart` contain `ShoppingCartSample`(s)? Do you have cycles that you want to map? Can you perhaps display a simplified code of your models? I need this info so I can answer the question most correctly, I am not sure if I understand it correctly at the moment.

Comment: Yes, ShoppingCart contains ShoppingCarSamples. And ShoppingCartSample contains ShoppingCart. I guess this could be called a cycle.

Comment: @guteFee could you share the model?

Comment: @xenteros I do not understand your question. Which model?

Comment: Your classes declarations

Comment: @xenteros I added the classes declarations

Comment: @guteFee and what do you want to map?

Comment: @xenteros I want to map Cart to ShoppingCart and CartSample to ShoppingCartSample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@AfterMapping` annotation like so:

```
@Mapper
public interface ShoppingCartMapper{
    ShoppingCart map(Cart cart);
    ShoppingCartSample map(CartSample cartSample);

    @AfterMapping
    default void setShoppingCartSampleParent(@MappingTarget ShoppingCart cart){
        for(ShoppingCartSample cartSample : cart.getSamples()){
            cartSample.setShoppingCart(cart);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [decorator](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators) and set the link yourself with an toher class, call automatically by mapstruct

your mapper

```
@Mapper
@DecoratedWith(MyMapperDecorator.class)
public interface MyMapper {
    ShoppingCart map(Cart cart);
    ShoppingCartSample map(CartSample cart);
}
```

Your decorator

```
public abstract class MyMapperDecorator implements MyMapper {
    private final MyMapper delegate;

    public ParticulierMapperDecorator(MyMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public ShoppingCart map(Cart cart){
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart = delegate.map(cart);//map the two objects
        //Set your link
        for(ShoppingCartSample sample: hoppingCart.getSampes()){
            sample.setShoppingCart(shoppingCart)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a cycle during the mapping. I'll post an answer later today that should be used for mapping cycles

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles) repository it uses the new (from 1.2.0) `@Context` to map cycles (which is what you have).

The code here as well:

```java
public class CycleAvoidingMappingContext {
    private Map<Object, Object> knownInstances = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Object>();
    @BeforeMapping
    public <T> T getMappedInstance(Object source, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
        return (T) knownInstances.get( source );
    }
    @BeforeMapping
    public void storeMappedInstance(Object source, @MappingTarget Object target) {
        knownInstances.put( source, target );
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `source` and `target` objects in the `CycleAvoidingMappingContext` can be more specific types, they don't need to be `Object`.

The mapper will look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
    ShoppingCart map(Cart cart, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
    ShoppingCartSample map(CartSample cart, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
}
```